# Converting data from sqlite3 database into an array format

Tags: python, sqlite

I have a problem where I am trying to call a specific field from the data recovered by the `self.results` variable from the [sqlite3](/questions/tagged/sqlite3) login database, although I am unable to do this as I believe that the fetched data is not in an array format and therefore the system is unable to use that field, I got rid of all the " ' ", "(", ")" but I do not know what to do now to convert this text file into an array so that a field can be fetched and printed.

Could you help me?

```
    while True:
        username = self.usernameEntry.get()
        password = self.passwordEntry.get()
        conn = sqlite3.connect("database.db")
        cursor = conn.cursor()

        findUser = ("SELECT * FROM students WHERE CardNumberID = ? AND Password = ?")
        cursor.execute(findUser, [(username), (password)])
        self.results = cursor.fetchone()

        fetchedResults = str(self.results)

        fetchedResults =  fetchedResults.replace('(', '')
        fetchedResults =  fetchedResults.replace(')', '')
        fetchedResults =  fetchedResults.replace("'", '')


        fetchedResults.split(',')
        print(fetchedResults[2])
        print(self.results)
```

Here are the results that I get:

[image: outcome <code>print</code> from logging in, into an account]

Comment: How is [tag:tkinter] related?

Comment: its just a portion of the code, shouldn't of included it my bad, kinda new to this

Comment: There's an [edit] button under the question for which you can use to improve your question any time.

Comment: ah yea i see it thank you very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The results *are* in an "array" format, but you then explicitly convert the whole thing to a string. Don't do that.